# Unable to close files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tabs

I have recently upgraded my eclipse to Mars, and .java files that were opened in my previous version are pinned and I'm unable to close.
In the image, first three .java files: CORSFilter.java, EmailController.java, EmailServiceImpl.java are stuck or pinned. I dont see an 'x' to close when i hover on the tab. I tried opening other files such as Assignment6.java and tried close all, but they still are stuck.

It does cause a havoc for having them there, but its little bothering to look at those windows while working on completely different project.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: I think i did re-install at that point

Comment: I have got the solution. I just closed the complete project and opened it again from the project explorer

Answer (score 9):

Closing and re-opening the project in the project explorer (and afterwards opening the files) solved it for me.

Comment: To do this, just right-click on the project to which you have an opened file. the click on close project. then simply double-click on it or right-click and open project again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you shutdown eclipse last time properly?
There is probably damaged file in eclipse i recommended you to 
1.reinstall it.
2.right click and try to kill tab. but the x on the tab no longer work and hidden bugs/error may happened due to damaged eclipse